# Python, tkinter how to prevent hiding/resizing widget during main window resizing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How I can disable widget resize and prevent hiding him when main window change the size ? Short video below explain my problem.

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> button = Button(root, text='BUTTON')
>>> button.pack()
```

```html
<video class="image-viewer horizontal" poster="https://thumb.gyazo.com/thumb/220_w/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpbWciOiJfYzU5OGFlZmVmNzdhYmMxMmJmZjI1YTM2M2ZiYTU4NTgifQ.EknroytPgpp5AzDXggtHrLMeHgKfTxHHKJjT8MiJJzU-gif.jpg" autoplay="" playsinline="" loop="" style="max-width: 220px; max-height: 100%;"><source src="https://i.gyazo.com/6262ec90a0e2599c547ceff9393e6d27.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Please post what code you have tried

Comment: @Zack Tarr, added in post.

Comment: Thanks answer is below, please mark if it helps :D

Comment: @Zack Tarr, that isn't help, I'm looking a little bit other solution :)

Comment: Check out that update to my answer and let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to stop resizing all together you will need the `resizable` line below in your program.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.mainloop()
```

If you would like to set a max and min limit to limit users so they do not hide a gui element you can use `minsize` and `maxsize` as seen below.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(width=40, height=50)
root.maxsize(width=100, height=100)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wanna left possibility to resize a main window and prevent hiding major widgets. :)

Comment: Updated the code to the best idea I have so far on solving that. Going to look around and ensure thats the best solution.

Comment: ty, this is one of possible solution, if I'm find other one - will post here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property `root.resizable(0, 0)` make the resize default button disbaled